# Is the Convolution of a Schwartz Function with an $ L^{p} $-Function a Smooth $ L^{p} $-Function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, convolution, schwartz-space

Let $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ p \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 1} $. If $ f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) $ and $ g \in {L^{p}}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) $, then it is a well-known fact from real analysis that the convolution $ f \star g $ is defined almost everywhere on $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and that
$$
\| f \star g \|_{p} \leq \| f \|_{1} \| g \|_{p}. \quad (\text{Young's Inequality})
$$
This implies that $ f \star g \in {L^{p}}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) $.

> **My question:** Is it true that $ f \star g $ is a *smooth* $ L^{p} $-function?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, the convolution is smooth. To see that this is so, you should convince yourself that you can move the derivative of $f \ast g$ on to $f$ or $g$. Since $f$ is smooth, you can differentiate the convolution by moving the derivatives to $f$ and using the fact that it is differentiable.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Dear Solomon, a related post is here, you may be interested, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509579/differential-operator-applied-to-convolution